# Cloud Firestore Rules: Why is Access Denied?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Working on a project with what I assume is a pretty typical structure:

```
Cloud Firestore
 |-users
     |-user1
         |-user1data
     |-user2
         |-user2data
```

Here's how my security rule is set up:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to write anything, I'm getting a FirebaseException "The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation." Can you spot anything wrong with the security rule? I need to allow all read/write for a given user within their collection in the database, while keeping each user's data separate. I could do this easily in Realtime Database but I can't seem to figure it out here.

EDIT: Here's the relevant code (I think)...

```
// CALLED FROM MAIN.DART
class Decider extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Decider({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final user = ref.watch(userProvider).value;
    if (user != null) {return const HomePage();
    } else {return const LoginPage();}}}

final userProvider = StreamProvider<User?>((ref) => FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges());

// SIGN-IN (WORKS)
onPressed: () async {
        try {
          await ref.read(authRepositoryProvider).signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: emailController.text.trim(),
                password: passwordController.text.trim(),
              );
          if (context.mounted) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                CupertinoPageRoute<void>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => const HomePage()));
          }
        } on FirebaseAuthException...

// CALLING CODE THAT SEEMS TO CAUSE THE ERROR
 ...onPressed: () {
                ref
                    .read(firestoreRepositoryProvider)
                    .addPayee(name: nameController.text.trim());
                if (context.mounted) {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              },...

// THE ADDPAYEE METHOD BEING CALLED
Future<void> addPayee({required String name}) =>
      _firestore.collection('users/$uid/payees').add({
        'name': name,
      });
```

Comment: It's hard to reasons about Firebase security rules without seeing the code that exercises them. Can you edit your question to show the [minimal code with which you can reproduce the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? In that code, make sure to prove how it meets the requirements of your rules - i.e. show what the current UID value is and that you indeed only try to access the data for thar user.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to reproduce the "minimal code with which I can reproduce the error," as it's spread out over multiple files throughout the project. That's why I asked if there was anything obviously wrong with the rule as written vis-a-vis the structure of the data being stored. I'll work through the code and see if I can produce some pseudocode that gets the gist across.

Comment: Nope, the rules looks reasonable. Hence the ask for the minimal code. Don't copy/paste from the existing files, but instead try to reproduce from scratch. That may seem like a big ask, but it's really the best way to increase the chances we can help (or you may catch the mistake yourself).

Comment: Not sure what this means, but...I reset the security rules to allow read/write for everyone, and the error disappears. However, when I log out of the app and then create a new user, two bad things happen: First, no new user document is created at the top level (i.e. 'users/$uid'). Second, I'm seeing user 1's records under user 2's login. In another location I'm watching ref.watch(userProvider.select((value) => value.valueOrNull?.uid and then using that in a Text object to verify the signed-in user. It shows a unique UID (i.e. not the one that shows up at /users/$uid)...

Comment: From that is sounds like your `$uid` variable does not always match the UID of he current user. A check like `if (uid != FirebasAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)` might help catch that.

Comment: Have you tried Frank's last suggestion?

Comment: I'm trying to. I've discovered more evidence, but haven't figured out what's causing it. In the drawer code, I have some debug text that displays the currently logged-in user's email and UID. They are correct (i.e. when I log in with my email address, it shows my email address and associated UID in the drawer). However when I assign a UID variable in my FirestoreRepository using what appears to be the same code (final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid) and inspect it using a breakpoint, the UID is wrong (i.e. not the one associated with my email).

Comment: I'm still having the problem, but I've noticed something else. The wrong data only appears the first time the list is displayed after logging in:
1. Log in as user1 (user2's data is displayed)
2. Log out as user1
3. Log in as user2 (user2's data is displayed)
4. Log out as user2
5. Log in as user1 (user2's data is displayed)
The uid variable in the FirestoreRepository is not being updated:
class FirestoreRepository {
  FirestoreRepository(this._firestore);
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore;
  final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
{...}

Comment: Can you try with this code [snippet](https://codefile.io/f/xRfWcWwCOd). Also `$uid` has no access in addPayee method, So you need to give access explicitly and pass the uid so it can be accessed.